# GetProcessIoCounters errors out with code 998

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, win32com, win32-process

I am trying to get the PIO_COUNTERS for the current process by doing:

```
DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
auto handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
PIO_COUNTERS ctr = nullptr;
if (!GetProcessIoCounters(handle, ctr)) {
  DWORD dw = GetLastError();
}
```

I get value of dw as 998 which is "Invalid access of the memory location". This essentially means that the handle I am using does not have enough privileges, but this is the flag with the max access control privileges. I also tried using the handle given by "GetCurrentProcess" (which is different from the one I got above) but that also gave error code 998 after passing it to GetProcessIoCounters.

Can somebody please help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not passing a valid pointer to receive the data. `IO_COUNTERS ctr = {}; GetProcessIoCounters(handle, &ctr);` etc.

Comment: Straight from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessiocounters): *"lpIoCounters: A **pointer to an `IO_COUNTERS` structure** that receives the I/O accounting information for the process."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'invalid access' error is occurring because you are passing a `nullptr` value for the address of the `IO_COUNTERS` structure into which to write the information you are retrieving. You need to give the address of an *actual* structure for this:

```cpp
DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
auto handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
IO_COUNTERS info;
if (!GetProcessIoCounters(handle, &info)) { // Pass the address of your structure!
  DWORD dw = GetLastError();
}
```

You can then access the various members of the `info` structure to get the information you want.